# MySQL Repair with Keycache performance

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MyISAM table with 125M records. I added 25M more records to it via:
ALTER TABLE x DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO x SELECT * FROM y;
ALTER TABLE x ENABLE KEYS;

Currently ALTER TABLE x ENABLE KEYS is in the "Repair with Keycache" state. How fast is this repair operation? Is it at least as fast as the case if I didn't disable the index and let rows be added with indexes updated on the fly or is it slower?

If I kill the query now, DROP all the indexes and then re-create them again to force repair by sort (my buffer sizes are large enough) would I risk losing any data?

Comment: You only risk losing your data, if you didn't backup it first. You did backup it, didn't you?

Comment: I do not think the data will be lost if you kill this query. But dropping all indexes and re-creating them will take time as well. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you kill the query while the ALTER TABLE operation is in progress, you risk losing any data that was added to the table after the ALTER TABLE operation began. Additionally, dropping and re-creating the indexes on the table would also cause you to lose any data that was added to the table after the indexes were dropped.

In general, it is a good idea to avoid making any changes to the table while the ALTER TABLE operation is in progress. If you are concerned about the speed of the operation, it may be better to let it complete rather than trying to interrupt it.

In terms of the speed of the operation, whether or not you disable the keys before inserting new rows into the table will not affect the speed of the ALTER TABLE operation. The ALTER TABLE operation will run at roughly the same speed regardless of whether the keys were disabled or not. The speed of the operation will depend on several factors, including the size of the table and the speed of the underlying hardware.

If you want to force the ALTER TABLE operation to use the "Repair by sort" method, you can do so by setting the myisam_repair_threads system variable to a value greater than 1 before running the ALTER TABLE operation. This will cause the operation to use the "Repair by sort" method, which may be faster in some cases. However, keep in mind that this will also use more system resources, so it may not be appropriate for all situations.

It is always a good idea to back up your data before making any changes to a table, in case something goes wrong. This way, you can restore the data from the backup if needed.